# In what form do I store the Windows clipboard data?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a Windows form application that will use the `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard` namespace.

There are ways to get and store the Text and Image data from the Windows Clipboard.

However, there may be a situation in which I want to Copy and store data containing both Text and Images/Audio simultaneously, e.g. the content from MS Word.

How do I get and act upon different types of data present on the Clipboard simultaneously?

Comment: What do you intend to do after acting upon data? Store it or paste it?

Comment: Did you read the Custom and Multiple Formats section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: I want to Paste it later on a trigger to an action. @nvartak

Comment: Going through the link you pasted, @ClayVerValen